# The 'core-cusp' problem for dark matter halos in larger galaxies

Tags: cosmology, simulations, dark-matter, galaxies, structure-formation

TLDR: Do observations of *larger* galaxies favour 'cuspy' dark matter halo distributions, as predicted by N-body simulations?

I've been trying to understand the ['core-cusp' problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuspy_halo_problem) for dark matter halos and I understand that observations of **dwarf** galaxies don't agree with the results of N-body CDM simulations.

What I don't understand is that, can it be taken by implication that larger galaxies *do* agree with these simulations, and if so, is there an expected 'cut-off' in terms of mass or radius where one would only expect to observe a 'cuspy' profile?